# How to increase the allocated memory for docker container?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a docker container running inside `WSL2`(`Ubuntu 20.04`). There is no Docker Desktop for Windows. Container is buidling Linux image using Yocto Project. Now, for a `clang` cross-compiling, I am running into out-of-memory issue.

```
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus compilation terminated.
```

So, I have to increase the `RAM` allocated for the conatiner. Is there any way to achieve this without Docker Desktop for Windows?

Thanks in advance,

P.S: Please let me know if ayn info is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

After quick Google search try this:

> You can configure the memory limit by creating a .wslconfig file in
> your user folder. Mine's C:\users\wme. Next add the following content
> to the file:
>
> `[wsl2] memory=48GB`
>
> Make sure to set it to a value that makes sense. I have 64GB so I set
> it to 48GB. That leaves me with a bit of memory to work with in
> Windows itself. Save the file after you're done.
>
> Now reboot WSL with the command: `wsl --shutdown`.
>
> You can verify the new memory setting by running command `free` in the linux
> distribution you have installed. It should list content like the
> following: [image: Screenshot1]
>
> [Source 1](https://fizzylogic.nl/2023/01/05/how-to-configure-memory-limits-in-wsl2)

[Source 2](https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2021/08/31/windows-en-wsl-2-memory/)

I hope this helps